# How do I Adjust for stock splits in Yahoo Stock Portfolio?

Tags: stocks, yahoo-finance

I have adjusted for stock splits before in my Yahoo Stock Portfolio and have printed out the steps but can't get it done now.  Step 2 says after you have loaded the portfolio, scroll over the **Modify** tab on the toolbar and choose Dividends/Splits from the dropdown.  I cannot find or see a **Modify** tab as many ways as I've tried.
How do I get this done?  Help!!

Answer (score 1):

To adjust your cost basis manually, you divide the number of shares after the split by the number of shares before the split (example: To adjust for a 2-for-1 split, divide 1 by 2. This gives you your adjustment factor of 0.5.). Then, multiply your cost basis prior to the split (or the historical price you want to adjust for) by your adjustment factor (0.5 in our example for a 2-for-1 split)

Answer (score 1):

Call me stupid, from a Finance app like yahoo finance that shows financial information, gets you keep control of your portfolio and SHOWS WHEN THE STOCKS SPLIT HAPPEN, I would expect the app to automatically adjust the number of stock in your portfolio in the same way they adjust the price per share in their platform.
It is ridiculous the user has to manually go to all their holdings to input manually the stock split and play with the price they bought the shares.
It defeats the purpose of having an app like that to keep track of your portfolio.